# Cannot open File because of special characters in Java

Tags: java

My problem is that I cannot open a file with special characters in Java.

For example,

I have a file like `solution/Testàtest.pdf` and if I run my java program in Linux with `java -jar program.jar`

I recieve that error message:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException

because he looks the path as `solution/Testtest.pdf` and not like supposed as `solution/Testàtest.pdf`

My code to open a File is:

```
File d1 = new File("solution/Testàtest.pdf");
```

So, have everyone an idea how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Is "soltuion" a typo in the path ?

Comment: Are you sure that this is right path ?

Comment: It's an encoding probleme 
try to encode your string to utf8 charset : `File d1 = new File(new String("soltuion/Testàtest.pdf".getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"));`

Comment: you can also encode the complete path of the file

Comment: @Berger: I have written a mistake it is not soltuion but solution here in the forum

Comment: @AdamKortylewicz: Yes, I am sure that is the right path

Comment: So,I used the idea of @bRIMOs Bor and that helped me to resolve the problem. Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

You probably have either a typo in your filename in Java or on the OS (as @Berger pointed out in the comments), or you have a String-encoding issue.

I run linux and have my Java-source-file encoding on UTF-8.

I have a file: /home/raudenaerde/ħ.txt   <-- notice the nice character :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("/home/raudenaerde/ħ.txt");

    System.out.println(f.exists());
}
```

When I run this:

true

If you are not sure about the java source file encoding, you could always use the unicode-escape ( in this case: `\u0127` )

To print your locale on linux, run the command:

`locale`